# Google-cloud-messaging key not visible in console

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

In my app gcm server key that is being used on server is not visible on google developer console.

Hence when i am trying to use google-services.json approach to integrate analytics its resulting in creating new key and project id.

how do i get google-services.json file for existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=gcm&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2Fandroid%2Fclient&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20GCM%20Support&%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue) to get a configuration file to add to your project. The configuration file provides service-specific information for your app. To get it, you must select an existing project for your app. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#prerequisites).